# Why does a rebase after a cherry-pick not apply the same commit twice?

Tags: git

When you cherry  pick a commit from one branch (say "topic") to another (lets call it "master") the history of that commit is rewritten, its hash changes and it effectively becomes a new, independent, commit.

However when you subsequently rebase topic against master git is clever enough to know not to apply to the commit twice.

Example:

```
A --- B <- master
      \
       \---- C ---- D <- topic

$ git checkout master
$ git cherrypick D

A --- B --- D' <- master
      \
       \---- C ---- D <- topic

$ git checkout topic
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying 'C'

A --- B --- D' <- master
            \
             \---- C' <- topic
```

How does this magic work? Ie. how does git know it should apply C to D', but not D to D'?

Comment: By the way, cherry-pick or rebase results really are new commits.  Git's checking out the files, running diffs, applying the results as patches and committing the results just the same as you would.  The old commits are still in your repo.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The answer is in the man page for [git-rebase](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html):

> Note that any commits in HEAD which introduce the same textual changes as a commit in HEAD.. are omitted (i.e., a patch already accepted upstream with a different commit message or timestamp will be skipped).

Rebase looks at the textual change, and refuses to replay that commit if it already exists on the branch you're rebasing onto.