# What are the consequences of using git rebase on cherry picked commits?

Tags: git

Suppose I cherry pick a few commits into my branch with `git cherry-pick`. After that, let's say I rebase my branch onto my parent branch to get latest. Will git still remember internally that these commits have been cherry picked? This is important because I do not want those commits to become dumb conflicts when I merge my branch back into the parent branch from which I cherry picked from.

Step by step for my example:

1. Create branch `B` from branch `A`
2. Commits are made on `B` and `A`.
3. Pull in the tip commit from branch `A` into branch `B` using `git cherry-pick A`
4. Rebase `B` onto `A` using `git rebase A` (with `B` checked out)
5. What happens when I run `git cherry`? Will it show the commit I cherry picked (which means it no longer remembers that commit was cherry picked)?

If the cherry-pick relationship is ended after a rebase, will the `-p` option in rebase fix it? Or is there some other solution to avoid it?

Comment: An ASCII graph would help in understanding *which* commits you're cherry-picking *where*.

Comment: I gave a contrived but simple example. I'm not an expert in the ways of ASCII art. Use your imagination.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does a rebase after a cherry-pick not apply the same commit twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509878/why-does-a-rebase-after-a-cherry-pick-not-apply-the-same-commit-twice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not show conflict in trivial case - when picked change is not affected by rebased changes (no changes in the same line range).

In all other cases there will be a conflict.

The only way to find out, what will happen, is to try doing this (in a separate branch).

Here is a [book](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) explanation:

> If the upstream branch already contains a change you have made (e.g.,
>   because you mailed a patch which was applied upstream), then that
>   commit will be skipped. For example, running git rebase master on the
>   following history (in which A' and A introduce the same set of
>   changes, but have different committer information):
>
> ```
>       A---B---C topic
>      /
> D---E---A'---F master
> ```
>
> will result in:
>
> ```
>                B'---C' topic
>               /
> D---E---A'---F master
> ```